# Calling FASTAPI to upload file from phone React Native

Tags: react-native, fastapi

I have a FASTAPI which accepts file as input in Heroku. I wanted to call the API from React Native app which user can select image from phone and pass it as a body. However, I have met an issue **{"detail": [{"loc": [Array], "msg": "field required", "type": "value_error.missing"}]}**. I wanted to know how should I structure the body and the requirements to be pass to the API. Here are the image info that I have:[image]

FastAPI Python

```
@app.post("/receiptOcr")
async def main(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
```

React Native

```
const chooseFromLibrary = () => {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({
      width: 300,
      height: 400,
      cropping: false,
    }).then(image => {
      console.log(image);
      hi(image.path);
    });
  };
  const hi = async imagepath => {
    let response = await fetch(
      'https://receipt-ocr-heroku.herokuapp.com/receiptOcr',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({file: imagepath}),
      },
    );
    console.log(response);
    let result = await response.json();
    console.log(result);
  };
```

Comment: You have to read the file and then send it from your react app . UploadFile expects a byte stream and now you're sending a file path. What does your swagger (for FastAPI) tell you about the content type?

Comment: As Charlie notes, you can't just send the file path - you'll have to send the content. If you're using `UploadFile` in FastAPI, it expects the content to be sent as multipart form-data, and you'll have to format your update request like that. If you're sending base64 encoded data as JSON, then you'll have to use a regular field name and then decode that base64 data on the server side (in your FastAPI app). In either case you can't just send the imagepath, you'll have to send the _actual file content_ in some way.

Comment: @CharlieV i did not set up the swagger as I am quite new to the API but i wanted to know what are the requirement for uploadfile. I have already read the documentation but still not really understand it.

Comment: @CharlieV This is the content type for the api. string($binary)
title: File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the automatic generated FastAPI swagger (127.0.0.1:8000/docs), you'll see that you have to use multipart-form to upload this.

[image: FastAPI Swagger]

To upload this from Angular you will have to use FormData as per the example below.

```
const chooseFromLibrary = () => {
  ImagePicker.openPicker({ 
    width: 300,
    height: 400,
    cropping: false,
  }).then(image => {
    console.log(image);
    hi(image);
  });
};

const hi = async image => {
  let uploadForm = new FormData();
  uploadForm.append("file", image);
  let response = await fetch(
    'https://receipt-ocr-heroku.herokuapp.com/receiptOcr',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: uploadForm,
    }
  );
  console.log(response);
  let result = await response.json();
  console.log(result);
};
```

Comment: what data is a must to be included in the uploadform?

Comment: The image from ImagePicker should be enough.

Comment: I manage to call the api but my api is using too much memory which cause error. It is all for nothing. Thanks for your help anyway!!